# In python how can i print only the first matching line from the log output?

Tags: python-2.7

I have input like this

```
line 1: [DEBUG]...
line 2: [DEBUG]... 
line 2: [DEBUG]...
```

From this I want to print only the first matching string meaning only
The first matching `line 1: [DEBUG]` and stop the traversing.

I have tried the code below:

```
for num1,line1 in enumerate(reversed(newline),curline):
    ustr1="[DEBUG]" 
    if ustr1 in line1:
        firstnum=num1
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not formatted very well, I cannot really see what your object is looking like etc.... I'd assume it's this way:

```
input="1: [DEBUG]....\n2: [DEBUG]...\n3:...."
# now you could do e.g.:
print(input.split("\n")[0].strip("\r"))
# which would be the first line. as you are searching a line containing a certain string "ustr1", you could do:
for line in input.split("\n"):
    if ustr1 in line:
        print(line)
        break #as you dont want more than one line
#furthermore, if you need the index of the line, do:
for i,line in enumerate(input.split("\n")):
     pass #i = index, line = line
```

Hope i understood it right ;)